# How to create chart when source is in Row whereas time variable in Column Headers

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have data arranged as in this example:

[image: Example of Data]

I have to do various analysis which I was able to do with the pivot tables and charts. The charts are also linked to each other with each other via slicers like this example:

[image: Expected output]

Problem: From this same data (or the pivot table) I have to make analysis (pivot of charts to show month by month analysis) as:

1. Different source (Month on the x-axis and three bars,
   baseline/target/actual, to show difference between each country,
2. Different country (countries on the X-axis with different bars of source),
3. Group the unique I.D based on the week they are starting (start
   date) or given first sale.

All the charts should be linked to filters/slicer. I do not know programming and I am a beginner using GETPIVOTDATA.